# magento 2.2.1vesion how to introduce customer CSS files or JS files?

Tags: customer

buddy:
   Now i'm contact the magento 2.0 vesion first time, before i contact the magento 1.0 vesion all the long time. Now i want to add a customer（customize） css file, and a customer（customize） JS file, But i don't konw how to do it?
    I have to via the google to found the Tutorial, but i couldn't found the good idea! So  i need your help from the stackoverflow!
   In magento1.0 version, i via found the app/layout/page.xml file, to add the customer CSS file, such as: css/mystyles.css
   But i don't know how to add customer css file in magento 2.0 vesion?
    Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.Make an entry in below xml**

**app/code/My_company/ModelName/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <link src="My_company_ModuleName::js/custom.js"/>
     <css src="My_company_ModuleName::css/custom.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
```

**2. Create custom js and css file in belows path.**

```
app/code/My_company/ModelName/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom.js

app/code/My_company/ModelName/view/adminhtml/web/css/custom.css
```